# Regex to match whole word in a sentence is not working

Tags: java, regex

I have created a regex to match the whole word in a sentence

```
.*\b(?i)USA\b.*
```

So, for below examples

1. `USA` --Matches
2. `The UsA`  --Matches
3. `USA is` --Matches
4. `India and USA is` -- Matches
5. `USAGE` -- Not Matches
6. `USA-`  -- Matches

for above 1-5, it is as per expectation but for point #6, it matches (Which was not expected).

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Why should `USA-` not match? `-` is considered a word boundary.

Comment: Thanks @Henry but is there any expression we can write which will not consider - (Hiphen) as a word boundary. My requirement is that only.

Comment: You need to be more specific what you mean by "whole word". Any other characters that are considered part of a word (except `-`)?

Comment: Blank Space, Tab,  New Line character (\n) and the start of the line should be considered as word separator, and if any word falls between any two of the above separator would be considered as a whole word.

Comment: `.*\b(?i)USA\b(?![w-]).*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get around this, you can us a negative look-ahead to fail the match if the following character is a word character or hyphen: https://regex101.com/r/46MaP7/1

```
.*\bUSA(?![\w-]).*
```